# Como fazer engenharia reversa em programa ou analise de dados

Tags: engenharia-de-software, engenharia-reversa, mql4

Ola, Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me informar algum programa para engenharia reversa de "dll", para estudo de estruturas de dados.

No caso queria desconstruir uma dll e analisar como determinado indicador é feito para se comportar em determinado gráfico de plataformas de negociação.

Comment: Sua pergunta é um pouco vaga. Mas existem sim ferramentas para fazer isso, se chamam [descompiladores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler).

Existe uma versao gratuita do [Hex-Rays](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) também se voce quiser começar com alguma coisa.

Comment: Dei uma editada na pergunta, mais seria no caso desconstrução de uma dll para analisar determinada estrutura de dados para entender como a mesma está interagindo com um gráfico de plataformas de negociação.